# Waiting for images to load after replacing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-isotope

I am making an AJAX call that replaces a div:

```
$.post(url, function(data) 
{
    $('#product_list').first().replaceWith(data.products);
});
```

My problem is that the images have a width of 100% and auto height.  This means that I must wait until images have loaded before I run isotope to fix the layout for masonry grid.

```
$('#product_list').isotope({ itemSelector: '.product'} );
```

When I am replacing with replaceWith() it will not fire off a `$(window).load()` after the images are loaded so I cannot figure out how to do this.

I know this isn't best solution as it will cause a visible jump to the user.  Best fix for me is to set the image height to a fixed height but I am using a responsive bootstrap grid so I cannot see anyway to do this as I need the image to fit 100% width of its container to maintain design.

I can't think my way around this problem.  I don't know how to trigger an event after the height of each image has been determined.

Comment: Maybe you don't need to know the height. Just use set timeout with a reasonable amount of time

Comment: Tried this and it does not work consistently.

Comment: You can use the [imagesLoaded](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/) jQuery plugin.

Comment: That plugin looks good, going to give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a JS img object and use the onload event of that image to trigger your own javascript code that does some bookkeeping and when all images have fired you fire your load event.

```
var $imgs = $('img'), total = $imgs.length, sum = 0;
$imgs.each(function(){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = $(this).attr('src');
    img.onload = function() {
        sum++;
        if (sum === total) {
          // all images have loaded, so you can fire your event.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Really nice idea!  It makes me wonder, do you think firing off the isotope() method after each image loads would be too much overhead? That might make the loading look a little more natural than re-arranging everything at the end in one go but I don't want to kill slow devices.

Comment: Depends on the number of images and how fast they load in succession. I think I'd just try it out and look how well it performed. Especially the mobile and older IE versions as they are the slowest of the browsers. You could also have a `setInterval` firing each second that reflows the page and remove it when all images are loaded. That would not cause a reflow after each  loaded image, but would still give you an updates screen each second or so. In the setInterval function you could even check if any images had been loaded since the last call and if nothing changed skip the reflowing.

Comment: okay. Make sure to mark the answer as the correct one if it turns out to be what you need

Comment: Still not sure why you wouldn't just use imagesloaded.js with isotope since it is so well documented and proven to work very well with isotope